# Query Out the Child Record From Parent list in order to get there Size

Tags: apex, soql, soap-api

We have a requirement in order to Find out the Child Record from the Parent List.

Parent Query: `list<Case> caseList = [
            select  Id, recordTypeId, Type, Sub_Type__c, Origin, WMG_Image_Batch_ID__c, ANN_Company__c,ContactId,
                    WMG_Client_Social_Security_No_Encrypted__c, WMG_Client_Account_Number_Encrypted__c, Product_Manufacturer__c, 
              (Select id From Associated_Documents__r) from  Case
        ];`

Is there any way i can get the (Select id From Associated_Documents__r) in separate list as i need for my requirement.

Comment: It already is a list, what exactly is the requirment?

Comment: Just wanted  to calculate  the size of (Select id From Associated_Documents__r  Which are Present in the caseList ;

Comment: size against each case or total size?

Comment: Total Size and count of the Associated_Documents__r which are child of Case present in the caseList

Comment: do you know the object api name of Associated_Documents__r? (Associated_Documents__r is child relationship name)

Comment: Case_Associated_Document__c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below code and note points:

1. Count of docs against each case - `eachCaseDocsCount`
2. Count of all docs - `totalDocs`
3. Count of all docs for caseList - `casesDocsCount`

Below is the anonymous apex code to find:

```
list<Case> caseList = [....];
Map<Id, Integer> eachCaseDocsCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();
for(Case cs : caseList){
    eachCaseDocsCount.put(cs.Id, cs.Associated_Documents__r.size());
}
System.debug('eachCaseDocsCount => '+eachCaseDocsCount);

Map<Id, Case> casesMap = new Map<Id, Case>(caseList); // collect map of id to case

Integer totalDocs = [SELECT Count() FROM Case_Associated_Document__c];
System.debug('totalDocs => '+totalDocs);
Integer casesDocsCount = [SELECT Count() FROM Case_Associated_Document__c WHERE Case__c=:casesMap.keySet()];
System.debug('casesDocsCount => '+casesDocsCount);
```

Assuming that `Case__c` is the field api name of lookup/master field to `Case` (If its different, replace it)